# Physics Bodies are being offset from their node upon creation

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I have been working on a puzzle game that uses a customizable grid with levels that are preset and created when the scene inits. They are comprised of static blocks scattered around the grid and a movable player controlled block. The gravity of the world is controllable and the block falls in that direction (up, down, left, right). I am using `SKContactDelegate` to track when the player block touches a block or the edge of the grid and stops it in place.

The problems I am having involve the physics bodies of the blocks and grid edge.

I am using `bodyWithRectOfSize` for the blocks and `bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect` for the grid border.

The physics bodies of 1x1 blocks placed in the grid and the player 1x1 block have normal physics bodies (as they should be). However, larger blocks ex: 1x5, the bodies are shifted down on the y axis for no reason. Also depending on the grid size, the grid edge would be offset by a random number. Note: the bodies are offset and the nodes themselves are in the right place.

This is the code for creating the blocks; this one works fine
(cellsize is the size of each grid space)

Basic 1x1 block

```
-(SKShapeNode *)basic {

    CGRect blockRect = CGRectMake(10, 10, self.cellSize, self.cellSize);
    UIBezierPath *blockPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:blockRect cornerRadius:8];
    SKShapeNode *blockNode = [SKShapeNode node];
    blockNode.path = blockPath.CGPath;
    blockNode.fillColor =[UIColor blackColor];
    blockNode.lineWidth = 0;
    blockNode.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:blockRect.size];
    blockNode.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = blockCategory;
    blockNode.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;

    return blockNode;
}
```

and custom blocks (offset down on the y axis)

```
-(SKShapeNode *)basicWithWidth:(int)width WithHeight:(int)height {

    CGRect blockRect = CGRectMake(10, 10, self.cellSize * width, self.cellSize * height);
    UIBezierPath *blockPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:blockRect cornerRadius:8];
    SKShapeNode *blockNode = [self basic];
    blockNode.path = blockPath.CGPath;
    blockNode.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:blockRect.size];
    blockNode.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = blockCategory;
    blockNode.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;

    return blockNode;
}
```

And here is the grid edge

```
SKShapeNode *edge = [SKShapeNode node];
CGRect edgeRect = CGRectMake(10, 10, 260, 260);
UIBezierPath *edgeShape = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:edgeRect cornerRadius:8];
edge.path = edgeShape.CGPath;
edge.lineWidth = 0;
edge.fillColor = [UIColor grayColor];
edge.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:edgeRect];
edge.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = boardCategory;
[self addChild:edge];
```

Note: The edge and blocks are children to a "board" node that is a child of the game scene

Thank you for reading this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `SKPhysicsBody`'s [`bodyWithRectangleOfSize:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKPhysicsBody/bodyWithRectangleOfSize:), it is centered on its node's origin. What you want to do in your case is center them on the center of the rect that defines your node. To do that, use [`bodyWithRectangleOfSize:center:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKPhysicsBody/bodyWithRectangleOfSize:center:) instead.

For example, you define your block with the rect:

```
CGRect blockRect = CGRectMake(10, 10, self.cellSize, self.cellSize);
```

So, you'll want your `physicsBody` centered on the center of that rect. You easily get the center of a `CGRect` with:

```
CGPoint center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(blockRect), CGRectGetMidY(blockRect));
```

To create the physicsBody centered there, use:

```
blockNode.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:blockRect.size center:center];
```

***Note:** `bodyWithRectangleOfSize:center:` is only available in iOS 7.1 and later*

---

**iOS 7.0 method**

For iOS 7.0, you can use `bodyWithPolygonFromPath:` instead, it just takes an additional line of code:

```
CGPathRef blockPath = CGPathCreateWithRect(blockRect, nil);
blockNode.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithPolygonFromPath: blockPath];
```

Comment: For some reason using  bodyWithRectangleOfSize:center: crashes the game. this is the error i get:  http://pastebin.com/7CQ2EB3m

Comment: What version of iOS are you running it on? It looks like `bodyWithRectangleOfSize:center:` is only available on iOS 7.1 and later. There's an alternate method for older OSes if you need it.

Comment: Ah yes my iPad was running 7.0.3. Also how would i go about fixing the edge loop issue? there does not seem to be a method allowing the center to be changed for edge loops. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your edge loop creation looks ok to me. Is it still an issue after fixing the physics bodies for the blocks?

Comment: Actually yes it's fine. I made a an adjustment and its started working. Thank you again for the assistance! I'm still not the most experienced at objective-c but getting help from you guys really eases the pain.

Comment: Glad I could help :) Be sure to mark the answer as accepted so that other people looking at your question will know that it's solved and what the answer was.